# Sending script to php file with URLLoader returns 0 when I try to GET it

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, urlloader

I have a game, I want to write score in my database when the game is over. This is the urlloader function:

```
public function gameFinished(){
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/../../sendScoreUnit4.php");
       var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
       requestVars.score = total_score_hard;
       req.data = requestVars.score;
       req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
       urlLoader.load(req);
    }
```

My sendScoreUnit4.php file tries to get the score like so :

```
$score = (int)$_GET['score'];
```

but when I echo it I get 0 every time.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ... `req.data = requestVars;`, then as you are sending a POST request : `$score = (int)$_POST['score'];` ...

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: In that case, try an absolute URL, and ensure that `total_score_hard` has a value/is not 0.

Comment: Remove the `req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;` from your code, or change it to `req.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;`